# Text not changing in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table

I seem to be doing something wrong in the following code: http://jsfiddle.net/yunowork/qKj6b/1/

When you click next, the text within the span `.hiddentext` should be displayed in the span `.showtext` on top and correspond to the right Race (Rn). For example when R3 is highlighted the content of that `.hiddentext` "Race 3
Oregon 14:30" should be displayed within the span `.showtext.`

This is the line where I make a mistake:

```
$('.showtext').text($('.hiddentext').first('td:first').text());
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: `.hiddentext` is a child of the `td`, and `first()` does not filter that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be

```
$('.showtext').html($('.highlighted .hiddentext').html());
```

Similar for the prev link...

or even better, thanks to @balexandre:

```
$('.showtext').html($nextCol.find('.hiddentext').html());
$('.showtext').html($prevCol.find('.hiddentext').html());
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qKj6b/6/)

Update to match @balexandre hint: [Fiddle 2](http://jsfiddle.net/qKj6b/21/)

Comment: he already has the column, it's always safer to use the column object rather then find the object itself from all code, the `$('.highlighted .hiddentext').html()` should be `$nextCol.find('.hiddentext').html()`.

Answer (score 2):

Let's start simple:

## Your problem:

```
$('.showtext').text($('.hiddentext').first('td:first').text());
```

you are saing, that, grab all `.hiddentext`, choose the first that has a `td` ... witch is not what you have in code, you have, td that contains hiddentext... so, the other way around.

[image]

What you want to do is simply get the current NEXT td and grab the hiddentext, so, just change to:

```
$('.showtext').text($nextCol.find('.hiddentext').text());
```

Now, can you see that the `<br/>` is not correctly rendered? That's because you are setting the `text` property, and you should set the `html` property.

[image]

the final code should be something like:

```
$('.showtext').html($nextCol.find('.hiddentext').html());
```

live example:  http://jsfiddle.net/qKj6b/8/

[image]

## Your code:

every time you need to have placeholders to provide some data to a context, please, DO NOT USE HTML TAGS to hold such values and hide them... make the use of the `data-` attribute, witch is a HTML5 complience, and works very well in any browser even if it does not have not HTML5 support, like IE6.

your table definition (`td`) that currently is:

```
<td class="visible" id="r2">
    <span class="hiddentext">Race 2<br />Santa Fe 12:00</span>
    <strong><a href="#" title="Race number 1">R2</a></strong>
</td>
```

should be something like:

```
<td class="visible" id="r2" data-text="Race 2<br />Santa Fe 12:00">
    <a href="#" title="Race number 1">R2</a>
</td>
```

witch is way easier to read, and from your javascript code, you can easily get this as:

```
var hiddenText = $nextCol.data("text");
```

## Your code (part 2):

This one is quite simple to know

> Every time you are repeating yourself, you're doing it wrong

You have the methods for Next and Prev almost exactly as each other, so, you are repeating everything, for this, you should refactor your code and just use one simple method, this way, any future change only happens in one place, and one place only.

```
$(".next").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var $nextCol = $('.highlighted').next('td');
    MoveCursor($nextCol, 'next');
});

$(".previous").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var $prevCol = $('.highlighted').prev('td');
    MoveCursor($prevCol, 'prev');
});

function MoveCursor(col, side) {

    var maxCol = 8;

    if((side === 'next' && col.length != 0) || 
       (side == 'prev' && col.length != 0 && col.index() >= maxCol)) {

        $('.highlighted').removeClass("highlighted");
        col.addClass("highlighted");

        // show current title
        $('.showtext').html(col.data('text'));

        if (col.hasClass("invisible")) {
            col.removeClass("invisible");        
            col.addClass("visible");

            var $toRem;

            if(side == 'prev')
                $toRem = col.next('td').next('td').next('td').next('td').next('td').next('td');
            else
                $toRem = $nextCol.prev('td').prev('td').prev('td').prev('td').prev('td').prev('td');

            $toRem.removeClass("visible");
            $toRem.addClass("invisible");
        }
    }
}
```

Live Example: http://jsfiddle.net/qKj6b/22/

Comment: Thanks for the extensive explanation, really helpful to see what I did wrong and what I need to improve, am still quite in the learning process.

Comment: here, you don't only learn your mistakes in code, but how you can improve your code habits as well ;)

Answer (score 1):

Do the following:

```
    var $currCol = $('.highlighted'); //to get the current column
    $('.race strong').text($currCol.closest('.highlighted').first('td:first').text());
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this (Same for both)

```
$('.showtext').html($currCol.find('span.hiddentext').html());
```

[**Working Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/qKj6b/13/).

Comment: replace `text` with `html()` to keep the linebreak

Comment: Thanks, I thought it was not an issue., bur updated the answer :-)

Answer (score 0):

`.hiddentext` class selects all the spans and the `first()` will always return you the first `td`.
Just make sure you select `.hiddentext` from the currently highlighted column and you are good to go.

`$('.showtext').text($('.highlighted .hiddentext').first('td:first').text());`